# No errors given and script isn't executed

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

As stated in the question before this, I have a registration system on my website and I am updating my mysql statements to PDO statements. I have updated all the statements and now the script runs through but it doesn't execute any of the script and doesn't give me any errors. It redirects me back to the registration.php page.

reg.php

```
<?php

include("sql.php");
    require("includes/password.php");

session_start(); //Start session for writing

$errmsg = array(); //Array to store errors

    $noterr = array();

$errflag = false; //Error flag

function UniqueID() {
    include("sql.php");
$UID = rand(); //Create unique ID
$check = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `UID` = :UID');

    $UIDarray = array(
        UID => $UID
);

    $check->execute($UIDarray);

if($check->fetchColumn() > 0) { //Check if it exists
    UniqueID(); //Redo the function
} else {
    return $UID; //return the uniqueid
}
}

$UID = UniqueID(); //Unique ID


$username = ($_POST['username']); //Username
$email = $_POST['email']; //Email
password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array("cost" => 10)); //Password
password_hash($_POST['rpassword'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array("cost" => 10)); //Repeated Password

//Check Username
if($username == '') {
    $errmsg[] = '<span style="color: red;">Where is your username?</span>'; //Error
    $errflag = true; //Set flag so it says theres an error
}



//Check Password
if($password == '') {
    $errmsg[] = '<span style="color: red;">Oops! No password!</span>'; //Error
    $errflag = true; //Set flag so it says theres an error
}

//Check Repeated Password
if($rpassword == '') {
    $errmsg[] = '<span style="color: red;">Your repeated password is missing!</span>'; //Error
    $errflag = true; //Set flag so it says theres an error
}

//Make sure passwords match
if(strcmp($password, $rpassword) != 0 ) {
    $errmsg[] = '<span style="color: red;">Passwords do not match</span>'; //Error
    $errflag = true; //Set flag so it says theres an error
}

//Make sure username is availible
if($username != '') {
    $qry = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `Username` = :username"); //MySQL query

            $params = array(
                  username => $username
          );

    $qry->execute($params);
    if($qry->execute($params)) {
        if($qry->fetchColumn() > 0) { //If username is in use
            $errmsg[] = '<span style="color: red;">Sorry, that username is already in use</span>'; //Create error
            $errflag = true; //Set flag so it says theres an error
        }
        $qry->closeCursor();
    }
}

    if(isset($_POST["captcha"])&&$_POST["captcha"]!=""&&$_SESSION["code"]==$_POST["captcha"])
            {
             }
     else
     {
    $errmsg[] = '<span style="color: red;">That is not what the picture displayed!</span>'; // Create error
    $errflag = true; //Set flag so it says theres an error
    }

//If there are input validations, redirect back to the registration form
if($errflag) {
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG'] = $errmsg; //Write errors
    session_write_close(); //Close session
    header("location: register.php"); //Rediect
    exit(); //Block scripts
}

//Create INSERT query
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `userauthenticate`.`users`(`UID`, `Username`, `Email`, `Password`) VALUES(:UID,:username,:email,:password)");

$params2 = array(
    UID => $UID,
    username => $username,
    email => $email,
    password => $password
 );

$query->execute($params2);

//Check whether the query was successful or not
if($query->execute($params2)) {
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit();
} else {
    die("There was an error, try again later");
}
?>
```

sql.php

```
<?php

ob_start();
session_start();

//database credentials
$dbhost = 'dbhost';
$dbuser = 'dbuser';
$dbpass = 'dbpass';
$dbname = 'dbname';

$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
?>
```

Comment: Because you have nothing to echo. Your code is just pure background processes.

Comment: When code doesn't work as expected DEBUG. SO is not a debugging service.

Comment: Logan, I don't want it to echo anything, I want the all that background processes to actually be processed. Nothing is being processed right now.

Answer (score -1):

It might be worth adding some try/catch blocks to catch any errors if there are any

```
//Make sure username is availible
if($username != '') {
    try {
        $qry = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `Username` = :username"); //MySQL query

                $params = array(
                      username => $username
              );

        $result = $qry->execute($params);
        if($result) {
            if($qry->fetchColumn() > 0) { //If username is in use
                $errmsg[] = '<span style="color: red;">Sorry, that username is already in use</span>'; //Create error
                $errflag = true; //Set flag so it says theres an error
            }
            $qry->closeCursor();
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException e) {
        // write the error to the log
        $errmsg = $e->getMessage();
        error_log('$errmsg-> '.$errmsg);
        echo $errmsg;
    }
}

    if(isset($_POST["captcha"]) && $_POST["captcha"] !="" && $_SESSION["code"] == $_POST["captcha"])
            {
             }
     else
     {
    $errmsg[] = '<span style="color: red;">That is not what the picture displayed!</span>'; // Create error
    $errflag = true; //Set flag so it says theres an error
    }

//If there are input validations, redirect back to the registration form
if($errflag) {
    $_SESSION['ERRMSG'] = $errmsg; //Write errors
    session_write_close(); //Close session
    header("location: register.php"); //Rediect
    exit(); //Block scripts
}

try {
    //Create INSERT query
    $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `userauthenticate`.`users`(`UID`, `Username`, `Email`, `Password`) VALUES (:UID,:username,:email,:password)");

    $params2 = array(
        UID => $UID,
        username => $username,
        email => $email,
        password => $password
     );

    $result $query->execute($params2);
}
catch(PDOException e) {
    // write the error to the log
    $errmsg = $e->getMessage();
    error_log('$errmsg-> '.$errmsg);
    echo $errmsg;
}

//Check whether the query was successful or not
if($result) {
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit();
} else {
    die("There was an error, try again later");
}
?>
```

Comment: Care to explain your reason?  If there are database errors this will catch the errors and if you look at the logs it will tell you what the are if they are not displayed on screen!!

Comment: You just bloated this code without a slightest reason. `ini_set('log_errors',1);` called **once** is enough.

Comment: Both this way and ini_set('log_errors',1); do not give me any errors.